# Counting maximum occurunces of items in a random series of numbers

Tags: excel

So, I have a series of numbers ,for convenience just 3,in cell A1,A2,A3. They are randomly created and hence can be any combination of 0s and 1s.
I need to find the maximum number of 1s that occurs at any instant of time and put the value in A4.
eg:

**Time t1:** (A1,A2,A3) are (0,0,0) -> result = (A4) is 0 [since no 1 is there]
**Time t2:** Time t1: (A1,A2,A3) are (1,1,0) -> result = (A4) is 2 [since there are 2 1s which is greater than 0 (at t1)]
**Time t3:** Time t1: (A1,A2,A3) are (1,1,1) -> result = (A4) is 3 [since there are 3 1s which is greater than 0 (at t2)]
**Time t4:** (A1,A2,A3) are (0,1,0) -> result = (A4) is 3 [since there is only a single 1 which is less than 3 (at t3)]

So the **final result is 3**

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of interval for time are we talking about ?  ie how often do the values in A1, A2, A3 change ?

Comment: The values (A1,A2,A3) are being calculated based on user input.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this on for size. First get a count of all the ones at any given time, like: (assuming cell A4)

```
COUNTIF(A1:A3,1)
```

Then, you want to have a running "max value" cell, that can check to verify that it is greater than the current count of ones. This can be done with a macro script. Right click on your excel tab, select "view code," and enter this code into the code window:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim OldValue As Range
Dim MaxValue As Range

Set KeyCells = Range("A1:A3")
Set OldValue = Range("A4") 'this is the current count of ones
Set MaxValue = Range("A6") 'this is the overall max number of ones

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then

    ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
    ' changed.
    ' Place your code here.
   If OldValue > MaxValue Then
        MaxValue = OldValue
   End If

End If
End Sub
```

When you are done in the code window, select `file > close and return to microsoft excel`

Comment: That doesn't satisfy his requirement that you have to take all times into account.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your feedback in comments, I would recommend the following:

1) Put a value of "0" in cell: B1.

2) In cell A4, put this formula: (very similar to W3AVE's answer) ..

```
=MAX(B1,COUNTIF(A1:A3,1))
```

Essentially, you need to store the highest value so far to accomodate that extra requirement you have to monitor values over all times.

After things are updated, you need to copy (values only) from A4 to B1.
You can do this manually, or have a small VBA script to do it.

But since it's updated on User input, a quick copy (values only) seems the simplest solution.

Comment: Is there a function in excel to copy only values without vba or manually?

Comment: when you copy manually, "paste => special" .. and choose values only.  If you want to see the VBA code, create a macro, and do the copy, and look at the macro code ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a User Defined Function that accomplishes what you want in a single cell:

```
Public Function HighestNumber(rng As Range, num As Long)

    Static highest As Long
    Dim tmp As Long
    tmp = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, num)
    If tmp > highest Then highest = tmp
    HighestNumber = highest

End Function
```

Call it from a cell with `=HighestNumber(A1:A3,1)`

Just note: if you close the workbook your previous "max" value is destroyed and the function is recalculated from scratch the next time you open it.